# Angular Directive not for child element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which i want to add to a div but not to its child divs.
I want a div to be draggable so that this div is draggable and its child divs are dragged with it. But i don't want the child divs to be able to drag its parent div.

Here is the HTML template

```
<div div-draggable id="chColorPickerWrapper">
    <div>
        <div id="colorDiv"> </div>    
        <div id="whiteToTransparent"> </div>
        <div id="blackToTransparent"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the directive

```
chDirectives.directive('divDraggable',['$document', function($document){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link : link
    };

    function link(scope,element,attrs)
    {
        var startX = 0;
        var startY = 0;
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;

        var mouseMove = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            y = event.pageY - startY;
            x = event.pageX - startX;

            element.css({
                top: y + 'px',
                left:  x + 'px'
            });
        }

        var mouseUp = function() {
            console.log('UNBIND');
            $document.off('mousemove', mouseMove);
            $document.off('mouseup', mouseUp);
        }

        var mouseDown = function(event){
            console.log('mouseDown');
            event.preventDefault();
            startX = event.pageX - x;
            startY = event.pageY - y;
            $document.on('mousemove', mouseMove);
            $document.on('mouseup', mouseUp);
        }


        element.bind('mousedown',mouseDown);
        element.css({
            position: 'relative',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            display: 'block',
        });        
    }
}]);
```

When i click on the colorDiv i don't want it to be draggable.
How can i overwrite or erase this behavior for the child divs ?

if you have any suggestions to make my code better i would appreciate that too, because i am fairly new to angularjs

EDIT:
here is a example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/K52DDXQRCME7S3oMimoC

Comment: can check `event.target` . Still not totally clear what the criteria is. Can you create a demo in jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co. Might also want to look at using something like http://draggabilly.desandro.com/

Comment: Just bind the events only when target element is the original parent should do it. `if (element[0]=== event.target) {
          $document.on('mousemove', mouseMove);
          $document.on('mouseup', mouseUp);
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mouseDown handler you need to check if `event.target` is that draggable element:

```
   var mouseDown = function(event){
            console.log('mouseDown');
            event.preventDefault();
            if( event.target === element ) {
              startX = event.pageX - x;
              startY = event.pageY - y;
              $document.on('mousemove', mouseMove);
              $document.on('mouseup', mouseUp);
            }
        }
```